# HttpPost action of a controller gets hit twice

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, http-post

Following is the exact scenario in my application.

[image: a busy cat]

I believe this picture is explaining the issue clearly. please do let me know if you have any questions in understanding the same.

The issues is the HttpPost action gets called twice causing two entries getting added in the database.

How can I prevent the 2 actions?

Comment: Could you please share your `form` and `.buttonInlineSave` html with us?

Comment: And it would be a great pleasure to see actual code instead of pictures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because you are adding a `submit()` handler to your form every time you click the button, therefore the second time you submit the form, it'll hit your action twice, the third click means three posts, and so on.

To fix this, amend your code to hook to either the `click()` of the submit button, or the `submit()` of the form only. My preference is the form submission. Try this:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'EditEntryInline',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.success) {
                window.location.reload();
            }
            else {
                // inform the user that the save didn't work
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Also, you should probably amend your selector to use an `id` so that this code won't hook up to the `submit()` event of every form which appears on your page.

Comment: Also he need `preventDefault()`

Comment: Thanks for your response, and clearing my understanding on this. but removing button click hookup didn't work.. it still calls the action twice

Comment: Grate... thanks.. event.preventDefault() did the trick.. Cheers mate.. Thanks both of you for valuable tips

Comment: @Nirman no problem. If this answer helped you fix the problem, please click the green tick to the left to mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: done, just wondering it is still working fine, just by adding event.preventDefault(), and I didn't remove the event wire up from any of the two events..

Comment: That's because the `preventDefault` stops any further submissions. You should really remove the `submit()` hook from the click event too.

Answer (score 1):

You're wiring up **another** one ajax submit on your actual form submit. Consider to put `return false;` at the end.