# HttpPost to Controller is null for e.preventDefault() in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have used `e.preventDefault();` function to restrict HttpPost action hit twice. Using the submit button, system called the `e.preventDefault();` function. After that, View return empty object to the controller. I have followed below link to correct HttpPost issue.

[HttpPost action of a controller gets hit twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722971/httppost-action-of-a-controller-gets-hit-twice).

How can I resolve this issue?

View Code

```
@model EmployeeManagement.Model.EmployeeModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditEmployee";

}


<h2>Edit Employee</h2>
<div>

@using (@Html.BeginForm("EditEmployee", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "EditEmployeeMsg" }))
{ 
    @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.employeeId)
   <div id="butonRight">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    <input type="button" id="saveCancel" value="Cancel" />
   </div>

    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.titleId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.TitleEdit)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.firstName)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.lastName)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.email)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date of Birth</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.dateOfBirth, new { @class = "date_view", @Value = Model.dateOfBirth.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date of Join</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.dateOfJoin, new { @class = "date_view", @Value = Model.dateOfJoin.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Position</td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.positionId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PositionEdit)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Division</td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.divisionId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DivisionEdit)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Office</td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.locationId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.OfficeLocEdit)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Salary</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.salary)</td>
            </tr>            
        </tbody>
    </table>

}
</div>
```

Controller Code

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditEmployee(EmployeeModel abcde)
    {
        bool updateResult = new EmployeeProvider().UpdateEmployee(abcde);            
        return Json(new { result = updateResult }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#EditEmployeeMsg').submit(EditEmployeeMessage);

}
);

function EditEmployeeMessage(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: this.method,
        url: this.action,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.result) {
                alert('Update Succesfully.');

            }
            else
                alert('Update Failed.');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('Update Failed.');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The question you're linking to is nonsensical (not your fault, but it doesn't help with explaining your issue). An action being performed twice in javascript is *usually* (not always) sign of accidentally adding an eventlistener twice. Also, please post any relevant code samples so we get an actual idea of your application and what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Could you please paste your code in order to allow us to help you. We cannot guess a solution out of thin air without your code.

Comment: I have edited and posted my code...,I'm using IE11

Comment: Did you see any errors in the Browser console ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your issue has to do with your browser type (in case you are using IE for example). Try to add the following to your code :

```
if (event.preventDefault) {
    event.preventDefault();
} else {
event.returnValue = false;
}
```

Comment: I added ur code but IE 11 pass null to controller.It's working on firefox and chrome...

Comment: This sounds odd, is your problem now that the action is being called twice or that the viewmodel is not being bound correctly? If it has to do with the action being called twice, did u try to add 'return false' to the end of your function after the ajax call?

Comment: If I use Firefox or chrome then the system pass values to the controller but when I use IE 11 then the system pass null values to the controller.I have used 'return false' end of the function but no result.

Comment: Hey! Try to serialize the form itself and pass it throught to the ajax call. It would help if you also check what are the values after serialization and before passing it on to the ajax call.

Comment: thank everybody for comments.I reset the IE then the issues are finished.